# Сортировка по COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Данный запрос делает выборку по числу повторений за последний час:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) FROM log 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, access_time, NOW()) <= 60
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY COUNT(item_id) DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Но проблема в том, что MariaDB считает число всех повторяющихся значений в 4 млн записей, которые есть в моей базе данных и выполняется более 5-ти секунд. Можно ли ускорить данный запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ускорения этого запроса надо сделать индекс, для ускорения поиска по дате:

```
create index log_date on log(access_time, item_id);
```

И переписать условие поиска на следующее:

```
access_time >= NOW()-interval 60 minute
```

Старайтесь всегда, все условия выборки писать так, что бы к колонкам таблицы не применялись никакие функции. Во первых БД приходится вычислять их поочередно для каждой строки и во вторых, использование индексов в этом случае становится невозможным, что приводит к полному сканированию таблицы.